# quartz scheduler: run on last day of the month

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger, cronexpression

I need to run a job on the last day of every month. i tried the following cron expression:

```
<property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 3 L * * *" />
```

but got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.
```

it doesnt like the `L`, but without using it, how can i run on the last day of the month?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just change your trigger to

```
0 0 3 L * ?
```

One of day of week or day of month needs to be `?`. You cannot specify both.

Comment: your expression has 1 less item in in then mine.. this is ok?

Comment: Yes, that's the year field. It's not mandatory, and if you put `*`, then it's the same as omitting the value.

Comment: I have tried it but not working.It gives error :java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "L"

Comment: @Sheo First, this question is answered and long inactive, better create a new one. Second, be more descriptive about your issues. Third, you seem to be informing 'L' where a number value was expected.

Comment: If anyone would wonder `3` in expression then it is time of day. This mean last day of month at 3.00 AM. If you want send explicate time then use this `{SEC} {MIN} {HOUR} L * ?` e.g.  `15 30 3 L * ?` it will execute on last day of month at 3.30.15 AM