# Quartz cron expression - last thursday of every month

Tags: spring, cron, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I am using Quartz Scheduling and Spring Batch and I need to run a particular job on the last Thursday of every month.

Is it possible to create such a Quartz cron expression?

Thanks,

Comment: this may be? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962011/quartz-scheduler-run-on-last-day-of-the-month

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**, [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) has a special character -- `L ("last")` --, which allows you to define expressions such as *the last friday of the month*.

To fire a job at, say, 10am, on the last Thursday (`5L`) of every month, you can use the following cron expression:

```
0 0 10 ? * 5L
```

Comment: How would you do the penultimate Thursday of every month?